# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable python error

Tags: python

I don't understand what i did wrong here

```py
  File "one.py", line 353, in containsCount
    count = sum(map(count, filter(lambda find: text in find, _list)))
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

And the full code is:

```py
    def containsCount(self, _list, text):
        count = 0
        count = sum(map(count, filter(lambda find: text in find, _list)))
        return count
```

Comment: what do you expect from `map(count, ...)`?

Comment: The first argument to `map` should be a function. Here you are giving it `count` which is an `int`

Comment: .. see [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: @tomjn what do you mean?

Comment: Your naming suggests that you're working with strings, so what are the numbers and summing doing there?

Comment: This is [`map`s definition](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map): `map(function, iterable, ...)`. As you can see the first argument is a function. You are passing an int...

Comment: @molbdnilo if self.containsCount(l, "bytesAvailable") == 1:

Comment: It seems you are over-complicating things with `map` and `filter`. Why not just `count = len([word for word in _list if text in word])`

Comment: @LisaBookout Try `sum (["4 bytesAvailable", "6 bytesAvailable"])` and see how it goes.

Comment: It helps to have a running example that we can work with. If you created a small `_list` and `text` then called the function, we could take that code and try it ourselves. Make it easy for us to help!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using `map()` wrongly. As I understand, you want to do the sum of all the elements of `_list`which contains `text`.

I am not sure to understand your approach, I see two possibilities:

1. Map the elements of `_list` to 0 or 1 (1 only if text is in this element), and then sum these elements
2. Filter the elements to only keep those you want, and get the length of the produced list.

Either way, you don't use them well, and I advice you to look at the documentation of map and filter, or tutorials on how they works (for instance w3shools about [map](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_map.asp) and geeksforgeeks about [filter](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/filter-in-python/)).

My advice on how to resolve is to get simpler, and use a generator :

```py
len([x for x in _list if text in x])
```

And you can combine it with `sum()` to optimise memory usage :

```py
sum(1 for x in _list if text in x)
```

Ask me in comments if you would like more on generators or why it optimises memory usage, or any other information